# Making xterm use unifont

Tags: fonts, xterm

This might be an exceedingly silly question, but I can't seem to solve it anyway. I want to use GNU's Unifont in xterm, and with the purpose in mind I installed the package xfonts-unifont, but to no avail; I do know I am supposed to use the -fn option for bitmap fonts, and (probably) something like "xterm*font: 7x13" in the .Xresources file, but for that I need to know the NAME of the bitmap font. Using "Unifont" or "unifont" didn't help.

Can anyone please suggest me exactly what I should write in my .Xresources file to make xterm use the bitmap version of Unifont? I don't want to use ttfs, not for xterm anyway. Thanks in advance. By the way, I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd recommend using an xterm alternative instead of customizing it.

But since you asked, there is this utility called xfontsel (in the x11-utils package) that gives you the font names for font resources. In this case, the font name you are looking for is `-gnu-unifont-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*`

You can test it on the command line using:

```
xterm -font '-gnu-unifont-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*'
```

So to answer your question, your .Xresources would contain this line

```
xterm*font: -gnu-unifont-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

and don't forget to reload it with `xrdb -merge .Xresources`

Comment: Thanks! What I got wrong the first time is a reboot is needed for xfontsel to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I never was able to find the name with `*` in it. However, when I placed the following in my `~/.Xresources`:

```
xterm*faceName: Unifont:style=Regular
xterm*boldFaceName: Unifont:style=Regular
```

After that, at the main terminal, I ran

```bsh
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

After restarting the system (I don't know if that was necessary, but I did it), my `xterm` text was displayed in Unifont.

By the way, I was never able to get Unifont displayed when I used `xterm*font`. For example, it didn't work with `xterm*font: unifont`, `xterm*font: Unifont`, nor with `xterm*font: Unifont:style=Regular`. I don't see any `-*-*-unifont-*-*-...` when I run `xterm -report-fonts`.

I realize that you've accepted an answer that uses a different procedure from your accepted answer. I wasn't able to get things working with that answer, which might be because I did things wrong. I think that the actual reason might be that I installed the font using

```bsh
$ cd /usr/share/fonts
$ mkdir -p unifont-fonts
$ cd unifont-fonts
$ wget -q https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/unifont/unifont-14.0.01/unifont-14.0.01.ttf
```

Then, to rebuild the font cache:

```bsh
fc-cache -f -v
```